# how to deploy python webservice on apache

Tags: python, web-services, apache

I'm a green hand in Python.I have got a simple webservice with python as following:

```
enter code here

import soaplib
from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase
from soaplib.core.model.primitive import String, Integer
from soaplib.core.server import wsgi
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array
from soaplib.core.service import soap

class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):

    @soap(String,Integer,_returns=Array(String))
    def say_hello(self,name,times):
        results = []
        for i in range(0,times):
            results.append('Hello, %s'%name)
        return results
if __name__=='__main__':

    try:

        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
        soap_application = soaplib.core.Application([HelloWorldService], 'tns')
        wsgi_application = wsgi.Application(soap_application)
        server = make_server('10.44.138.231', 9999, wsgi_application)
        server.serve_forever()

    except ImportError:

        print "Error: example server code requires Python >= 2.5"
```

it's very fast when I access the service in localhost,but it will become very slow from the another host in local area network.

so I want to deploy this program in apache,but it seems hard,I search this in google for a long time and it makes me very tired now. who can give me a help,Thank you

Comment: [This](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (rather than `mod_python`), as WSGI is the standard way to host Python web applications.

You need to have a function called `application` in the global scope, in your case:

```
        # ....
        return results

soap_application = soaplib.core.Application([HelloWorldService], 'tns')
application = wsgi.Application(soap_application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ....
```

You then enable mod_wsgi in Apache and add directives in (`WSGIScriptAlias` is the main one). The [help pages](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp) are reasonably accessable if you've configured Apache before.

Answer (score 0):

As your webservice uses [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/) to serve the files, you can use any WSGI-compliant Apache module, e.g. [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

You can also use a standalone WSGI server like [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and then pass on the requests from your primary web server to the Gunicorn server process.

In case you're not required to use Apache: [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) combined with Gunicorn or uwsgi is a very widely used solution to serve WSGI apps.